# Does php PDO cope with MySQL collisions?

Tags: php, mysql, asynchronous, multiple-users

I bet this is answered elsewhere but I don't know the right terminology.

I'm using php (with prepared queries in PDO, not `mysql_*`) to query a MySQL database. Everything works great testing with only myself as a user, but weird stuff occasionally happens when we test with multiple users accessing the DB simultaneously, as if some queries are just silently disappearing.

Is it possible that there is some collision at the MySQL end, and errors are being thrown? (If so, I'm not seeing them...) Or does the PDO `$statementHandle->fetchAll(...)` wait around for any traffic to clear, and then execute (learned below: *yes*, what a relief)? If it's collisions, what's the right terminology (learned below from comments: table and row *locking*), and where should I look for best practices to cope?

In the javascript that invokes the php, I'm comfortable with Promises and `async/await`.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you elaborate more on the disappearing and the weirdness?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Do you mean some queries are failing silently? Do you do any error checking or logging of your queries?

Comment: I am relatively new to this, so checking and logging --- I may be doing it wrong, mistaking php errors for MySQL errors, etc. ATM, of course, I can't get it to throw an error to give an example.

But the symptom is as if I asked for a query to be executed and it simply was ignored. So I'm wondering if the DB locks up while the other user is `INSERT`ing or something.

Comment: If it locks, the query will wait until it is released. If your db engine is innodb it use row level locking, if it is myisam it is table locking. Perhaps you are catching the exception, that is why you can't see the error. Without codes to look at I can only guess

Comment: Have you set an error mode for PDO?  Have you done any validation when inserting the row to make sure it actually went through?  Row or table locking does exist, but it doesn't just silently fail, it would just delay the query until the lock releases to provide consistency.

Comment: For debugging purposes, set error attribute to throw an exception `$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);`

Comment: Please explain why you mentioned Javascript, promises, and async. If I had to guess then you are running into a race condition due to your JS somewhere.

Comment: Do you have multiple queries where the next one relies on the result set of the previous one?

Comment: @SpacePhoenix Yes, exactly. In addition, the various users are polling the DB, waiting for various conditions to be met. They change values in the common DB, which are then reflected (in the JS) in all users' UIs. So I use Promises to ensure that the various asynchronous calls are completed before going ahead and perhaps getting ahead of themselves.

Comment: THANKS to all! Everything is (currently) working correctly. Special gratitude for help with setting error attributes and helping with my missing vocabulary (which helps a LOT in searches): table and row _locking_; _race condition_.

Comment: @TimErickson you might want to consider using transactions